# Super POM Manifest Entries not being used

Tags: maven, pom.xml, maven-jar-plugin, parent-pom

We have a corporate wide super-pom that we use. It sets up all of the `mvn site` reports, making sure that all of the users are using Findbugs, PMD, etc.

One of the things we want to do is add entered to our `MANIFEST.MF` file. The entries help us pin down a particular jar to a particular Jenkins build and Subversion revision. The manifest looks like this:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Archiver-Version: Plexus Archiver
Created-By: Apache Maven
Built-By: david
Build-Jdk: 1.7.0_55

Name: Build-Information
Project-Name: tc-jsonp-filter-trunk
SVN-Revision: 23928
Build-Number: 23

Name: Module-Information
Group-ID: com.travelclick
Version: 5.1
Artifact-ID: tc-jsonp-filter
```

If I add the following to the local `pom.xml`, everything works fine:

```
<build>
    ...
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <manifestSections>
                        <manifestSection>
                            <name>Build-Information</name>
                            <manifestEntries>
                                <Project-Name>${env.JOB_NAME}</Project-Name>
                                <Build-Number>${env.BUILD_NUMBER}</Build-Number>
                                <SVN-Revision>${env.SVN_REVISION}</SVN-Revision>
                            </manifestEntries>
                        </manifestSection>
                        <manifestSection>
                            <name>Module-Information</name>
                            <manifestEntries>
                                <Group-ID>${project.groupId}</Group-ID>
                                <Artifact-ID>${project.artifactId}</Artifact-ID>
                                <Version>${project.version}</Version>
                            </manifestEntries>
                        </manifestSection>
                    </manifestSections>
                </archive>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
    ....
</build>
```

However, if I add this to my super-pom, the `MANIFEST.MF` file does not contain this information.

I know the super-pom is being downloaded (I can see that), and I know that other areas are working because it does JaCoCo test coverage, and that's only found in the super-pom.

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue:

My first attempt was using another plugin: [org.apache.felix#maven-bundle-plugin](http://felix.apache.org/site/apache-felix-maven-bundle-plugin-bnd.html). This wasn't working, so I tried the `org.apache.maven.plugins#maven-jar-plugin` archive configuration. This worked locally.

I then replaced my super-pom project with this change in my Maven repo, then deleted the `$HOME/.m2/repository/.../super-pom.xml` from my machine and tried it. It didn't work.

What I didn't realized is that I stored that super-pom in my *plugins* repository and not my *release* repository. Thus, it downloaded the older and incorrect `super_pom`.

Putting the super_pom in the correct directory solved the issue.